# Loading custom phtml file in an existing template issue in adminpanel

Tags: magento-1

I want to add some js code for the Associate to website field when you create a new customer. 
This is the xml responsible for loading that dropdown with the stores:

```
<scope_switcher>
        <block type="enterprise_customer/adminhtml_form_renderer_fieldset_element" name="fieldset_element_renderer" template="enterprise/customer/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml" />
        ......
</scope_switcher>
```

So i created my own module and tried the following in the my layout xml:

```
<scope_switcher>
        <reference name="fieldset_element_renderer">
            <block type="core/template" name="mynamespace_mymodule_fieldset_element_renderer" template="mynamespace_mymodule/enterprise/customer/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml" />
        </reference>
</scope_switcher>
```

and in my new template (element.phtml) , I want to add my js code. The fact is that my new template it is not loaded. The path is correct. Any idea what did I do wrong ? thx

Answer (score 0):

On your custom layout xml, you are creating a new block inside "fieldset_element_renderer" block.

To add a custom js file, You can reference the head block and use the addItem method for this. ([where-how-to-add-custom-js-magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477664/where-how-to-add-custom-js-magento))

If you want use the mynamespace_mymodule_fieldset_element_renderer phtml file, you need call it with `getChildHtml` method inside `enterprise/customer/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml` or use `setTemplate` action to change the current element.phtml file (you can see this second way bellow).

```
<scope_switcher>
    <reference name="fieldset_element_renderer">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mynamespace_mymodule/enterprise/customer/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</scope_switcher>
```

Note that in this way you will be changing the phtml the dropdown code should also be on file of your module, not just your js custom code.